# How to make a button that, when hovered on, slides over and reveals links (JS)?

Tags: javascript, animation, button

Could anyone guide me in created a simple app in JS?

What the app is is this:
There will be a button that says "Themes" and when you put your mouse over that button, it slides over to the left, revealing two links (the links will say "Light" and "Dark").

I'm not that experienced with JS, so could someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Kind of a vaugue question. How good are you with CSS? Anyway, download http://jquery.com. Include it on your page and then include js like this `$(document).ready(function(){ $('.ClassOfTheButton').mouseenter(function(){ /* Animiation code here */ }).mouseexit(function(){ /* Animation code here */ })`

jquery provides functions to perform animation

Comment: Removed 1 invalid tag and added another.

Comment: This site is about helping programming question. This sound more like we should do something for you. At least give it a try and tell us how far you got. I would expect will get more answers as for this question. (Also include some HTML to make your question more clear.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version with pure CSS transition http://jsfiddle.net/69z3y/

Comment: This is the one I went with, thank you so much. Thanks so much to everyone else too!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that slides the overlay:
http://jsfiddle.net/vWpmT/3/

Here is an example that squeezes the overlay until it has no width:
http://jsfiddle.net/vWpmT/2/

It requires jQuery.
The CSS given is the bare minimum needed except for the Background color.

Answer (score 2):

ahh you beat me to it:
http://jsfiddle.net/5Ls9y/

Answer (score 2):

This method uses a pure **JavaScript Animation Engine** that mimics jQuery animations in a few ways!

Reference:  [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xHJd7/)

The jsFiddle shows just 1 of many native JavaScript Animations.

For the complete list of animation examples that are ready to use as well as the related tutorials, check out the links in the HTML comments section for more info.

For **inspiration**, check out this webkit CSS3 Sliding [**Demo and Tutorial**](http://www.zurb.com/playground/sliding-vinyl) of a record coming out of album.

**Status Update:** If your Button is a image then these [**5 Demos for CSS3**](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/3DHoverEffects/) browsers is nice.